# Apply same sql connection string to whole winform?

Tags: c#

I would like to apply my connection string to the whole winform. If I do this in this case - it will apply to the whole win form, but then i cannot use textbox to enter details:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=userName;" +
    "password=userPass;" +
    "server=.;" +
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
    "database=dbName; " +
    "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" +
    "connection timeout=30");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And if I will use with textbox I will need to enter the connection string to each method.

Is there anyway to get around it?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you can take is create the SqlConnection when it is needed and then store in a private variable if you want to save the reference.

So when you need the connection have:

```
if( myConnection == null )
{
    string connectionString = string.Format( "user id={0}, password={1}", userIdTextBox.Text, passwordTextBox.Text );
  myConnection = new SqlConnection( connectionString );
}
```

You will extend the "string.Format" to include the other connection properties.

If you require the "myConnection" in multiple places then place the above code into a method named "GetConnection", have it return an SqlConnection instance using the contents of the textboxes and call this method each time a connection is required.

EDIT:

Personally I would have a method that builds the connection string, like described above, and create a new SqlConnection instance whenever it is needed. This will attempt to open a new connection each time, but will make use of connection pooling built into the ADO.NET library.

```
using( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection( this.GetConnectionString() ) )
{
    //  Open Connection
    //  Access the database
    //  Close the connection <- Manual closing MAY not be needed as it might be done in Dispose ...check MSDN for clarification.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static class to store the connection string in there. It is not a good practice to create always the connection string.